# Compare two return values

Tags: java, oop

How do I compare two return values from my method? Because when I'm doing this in my code and I'm expecting the return values to be the same, they are comparing as different. Here is my code:

```
public static void Card_Initialization(){

    Red_Dog c1 = new Red_Dog();
    Red_Dog c2 = new Red_Dog();
    Cards_Match(c1);
    System.out.println(card_num+card_suit);
    Cards_Match(c2);
    System.out.println(card_num+card_suit);
    System.out.println(Cards_Match(c1) == Cards_Match(c2));//to check really if it is equal
}

public static int Cards_Match(Red_Dog rd){
     card = (int)(Math.random() * deck.length); 
     if(card >= 0 && card <=3)
     {
        card_num = cards[0];
     }
     else if(card >= 4 && card <=7)
     {
        card_num = cards[1];
     }
     else if(card >= 8 && card <=11)
     {
        card_num = cards[2];
     }
     else if(card >= 12 && card <=15)
     {
        card_num = cards[3];
     }
     else if(card >= 16 && card <=19)
     {
        card_num = cards[4];
     }
     else if(card >= 20 && card <=23)
     {
        card_num = cards[5];
     }
     else if(card >= 24 && card <=27)
     {
        card_num = cards[6];
     }
     else if(card >= 28 && card <=31)
     {
        card_num = cards[7];
     }
     else if(card >= 32 && card <=35)
     {
        card_num = cards[8];
     }
     else if(card >= 36 && card <=39)
     {
        card_num = cards[9];
     }
     else if(card >= 40 && card <=43)
     {
        card_num = cards[10];
     }
     else if(card >= 44 && card <=47)
     {
        card_num = cards[11];
     }
     else if(card >= 48 && card <=51)
     {
        card_num = cards[12];
     }

     if(card % 4 == 0)
     {
        card_suit = suits[0];
     }

     else if(card % 4 == 1)
     {
        card_suit = suits[1];
     }

     else if(card % 4 == 2)
     {
        card_suit = suits[2];
     }

     else if(card % 4 == 3)
     {
        card_suit = suits[3];
     }

     return card;   
}
```

Result: 1st run:

> AceSpades AceSpades false

2nd run:

> AceSpades AceSpades true

Comment: Lol i don't know how to edit a while ago that's why I posted again. lol. funny.

Comment: Just click "edit". The link is under the tags "java" and "oop" at the bottom of your question.

Comment: I have answered your original question. Please, take a look there.

Comment: @RubioRic that would be appropriate if the OP was using an object.

Comment: So we now have two identical questions, asked no more than 15 minutes apart, because OP is learning how to use the site. Which do we close? I'm voting close on the other one.

Comment: @PeterLawrey What do you mean? I think OP's algorithm got a lot of failures. You have coded a completely different one, haven't you? It's a good anwser (I've upvoted). I hope OP learn from it.

Comment: @ErickG.Hagstrom Maybe the other one. This have a good solution.

Comment: @RubioRic I wasn't arguing with you, just pointing out there was some many things wrong with it.

Comment: @PeterLawrey At first I though that you were disputing the duplicate flag. No problem. Thanx for the comment. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of passing the RedDod object and then ignoring, I suggest you make the method non-static and only set fields of that class.

```
import java.util.Random;

public class RedDog implements Comparable<RedDog> {
    private final Suit suit;
    private final Face face;

    enum Suit {
        CLUB, SPADES, DIAMONDS, HEARTS
    }
    static final Suit[] SUITS = Suit.values();

    enum Face {
        ACE, TWO, THREE, FOUR, FIVE, SIX, SEVEN, EIGHT, NINE, TEN, JACK, QUEEN, KING
    }
    static final Face[] FACES = Face.values();

    static final Random RAND = new Random();

    public RedDog(Suit suit, Face face) {
        this.suit = suit;
        this.face = face;
    }

    public static RedDog random() {
        return new RedDog(SUITS[RAND.nextInt(SUITS.length)], 
                          FACES[RAND.nextInt(FACES.length)]);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        RedDog c1 = RedDog.random();
        RedDog c2 = RedDog.random();
        System.out.println(c1 + " and " + c2 + " equals is " + c1.equals(c2));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) { // generated by my IDE
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        RedDog redDog = (RedDog) o;

        if (suit != redDog.suit) return false;
        return face == redDog.face;

    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() { // generated by my IDE
        int result = suit != null ? suit.hashCode() : 0;
        result = 31 * result + (face != null ? face.hashCode() : 0);
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() { // generated by my IDE
        return "RedDog{" +
                "face=" + face +
                ", suit=" + suit +
                '}';
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(RedDog r) {
        int cmp = suit.compareTo(r.suit);
        if (cmp == 0)
            cmp = rank.compareTo(r.rank);
        return cmp;
    }
}
```

prints

```
RedDog{face=KING, suit=SPADES} and RedDog{face=QUEEN, suit=DIAMONDS} equals is false
```

Comment: Thank you so much Peter! :) Though I'm trying to do it now but still, thank you! :)

Comment: @JonathanNelsonCastillo I hope you can see that you really want to use OOP (and your IDE to generate the equals/toString for you)

Comment: Hey peter just a quick question. How can you compare the values of c1 and c2. Like for example, c1 is KING SPADES while c2 is QUEEN HEARTS, how do I compare syntax to calculate which is higher? Thank you! :)

Comment: @JonathanNelsonCastillo You first have to decide what the ordering should be, it depends on the same. e.g. is ACE > TWO or ACE > KING, or HEART > DIAMONDS. Then you can make the class implement `Comparable<RedDog>`

Comment: Oh. THanks Peter! I would try onto that. I used .ordinal() method and it worked but your suggestion seems better. Thank you again! :D

Comment: @JonathanNelsonCastillo I have added a compareTo at the end.  To change the order, you can re-arrange the enum constants, latter is higher.